# Drawing in Linux using c++ and create bitmap

Tags: c++, linux, bitmap

I have a crazy requirement where I need to create a bitmap in a c++ application by reading an xml file which has objects like a line, rectangle circle and Text. But this application does not have any GUI , window etc. I will have to do the drawing on memory using drawing libraries and save it as a bitmap. Its possible in c# , but I am not sure if its possible in Linux. 
Are there any libraries available in Linux for drawing ? without using any kind of window or form (GUI) . 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

The Cairo graphics library is one option: http://cairographics.org/ . This is also [under consideration](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3888.pdf) for being the basis of a future C++ 2D graphics library